# Show version info only once on application start in Android App

Tags: android, dialog, startup

I´d like to show a simple information dialog with an Ok-Button, about whats new in this version, but it should show only at the first start. Whats the best way to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would (and have) used a SharedPreferences with a boolean or int value. Simply check if the last version is older than the current version and update the int.
Here's a nice little snipit.

```
//check to see if we need to show whats new or not
        SharedPreferences config = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_STRING, 0);
        int lastVersion = config.getInt(KEY_VERSION, -1);
        if(currentVersion > lastVersion ){
showDialog(id);
//set this as lastVersion
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of solutions are documented here:

[What is SharedPreferences in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608483/what-is-sharedpreferences-in-android/3608517#3608517)

Answer (score 0):

with a boolean variable stored somewhere : preferences, DB, SD card, ..