# How to show Android preferences screen on app launch?

Tags: android

I am very new to Android development.
I want my Android app to launch the preference page the first time it is run.
Any tips on how to do that ?
Thanks.

Comment: what "preference page" are you referring to? Is this your app's preference dialog, or a particular Phone Preferences dialog for things like Network connectivity and other phone/device settings?

Comment: Like this?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612978/show-version-info-only-once-on-application-start-in-android-app

or?:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608483/what-is-sharedpreferences-in-android/3608517#3608517

Comment: Like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612978/show-version-info-only-once-on-application-start-in-android-app

or:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608483/what-is-sharedpreferences-in-android/3608517#3608517

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu will need to use sharedpreference to save boolean preference.

This should work for you.

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
boolean previouslyStarted = prefs.getBoolean("PREVIOUSLY_STARTED, false);
if(!previouslyStarted){
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_previously_started), Boolean.TRUE);
            edit.commit();
showPreference();//Here you launch your Preference Activity if it hasnt been launched before.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Store a hidden preference like 'has_launched_before' or something.  On startup, check that preference, and if it is false, show the preferences screen instead of the main screen, and also set that preference to true so it doesn't happen on subsequent launches.

Comment: Thanks, I tried opening the Preference page in onStarting(), but it crashes my app. Any ideas why ?